# Python Find a word in a list

Tags: python

Hello so I have to do a program that identifies all of the positions where a word occurs in a list but when I run my program it doesn't output anything.
Here's my code :

```
sentence =("ASK NOT WHAT YOUR CONTRY CAN DO FOR ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR CONTRY") #This is a list
print (sentence)
text = input("Choose a word from the sentence above")#this prints out some text with an input 
sentence = sentence.split(" ")# This splits the list 
text = text.upper ()# this makes the text in capital letters
def lookfor ():
    if text in sentence:
        for i in sentence:
            value = sentence.index(sentence)
            print ("Your word has been found in the sentence at the position", value + "and", value )


        else:
            print ("The word that you have typed is not found in the sentence.")
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you consider calling your function?

Comment: Or Googling for the dozens of other people cheating on the same homework?

Comment: and just to clarify, your sentence variable is actually a Tuple, and not a list

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions, nothing is happening because you aren't calling the function.

There's a lot of work remaining on your function, but here are some general tips:

1) Index only finds the first instance of an element in a list

2) You can't be sure that a word is in your sentence exactly twice

3) Use descriptive variable names.  For example, `for word in sentence` makes a lot more sense intuitively

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
sentence =("ASK NOT WHAT YOUR CONTRY CAN DO FOR ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR CONTRY") #This is a list
print (sentence)
text = raw_input("Choose a word from the sentence above: ")#this prints out some text with an input 
sentence = sentence.split(" ")# This splits the list 

text = text.upper ()# this makes the text in capital letters
def lookfor (text):
    indexes = [ idx+1 for word, idx in zip(sentence, range(0,len(sentence))) if text == word ]
    print ("Your word has been found in the sentence at these positions", indexes )

    if not indexes:
         print ("The word that you have typed is not found in the sentence.")

lookfor(text)
```

Example:

```
ASK NOT WHAT YOUR CONTRY CAN DO FOR ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR CONTRY
Choose a word from the sentence above: for
('Your word has been found in the sentence at these positions', [8, 14])
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have one more question, can you explain to me what this line do does ? indexes = [ idx+1 for word, idx in zip(sentence, range(0,len(sentence)))

Comment: this is called "list comprehension" in python, it creates a list of indexes each one corresponding to the position of every word in "sentences" and appends it to the list only if it matches the typed text

Comment: @tom3883 well you need to mark this issue as resolved